# How to post xml data in url as request?

Tags: iphone, post

I am developing an application in which i want to post

xml data as request but i am not able to post it correctly ,i think.

My request xml data is

`<loginRequest><username>101</username></loginRequest>`

and my request is as follows :

```
`NSString *post=@"<loginRequest><username>101</username></loginRequest>";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my url"];
__block  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *mutData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"body"];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSData *data=[request responseData];

            NSString *response=[request responseString];
        }];
        [request setFailedBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"Failed");
        }];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

`

Kindly help me with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with your server api whether it supports different response type..
Accordingly you can set "Accept" parameter of HTTP request header.

[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/xml"];